# Is it possible to plug a home theater (like in the old days) to a computer and mount it like an external drive?

Tags: digital-recording, bluray

I have a Blu-Ray compatible home theater from Sony (BDV-EF200) and I'm wondering whether it would be possible to get some kind of "digital" data directly to my computer, rather than reading the stream using an HDMI cable connected to a "Video Capture" HDMI->USB adapter.

In summary, I have the appropriate laser to read blu-rays (from the home theater), and I'm wondering what kind of trick I could use to plug the flexible pins that come out of the disk reader into something that can mount it as a drive on my computer.

Is this possible in practice?

My current belief is that it would be possible in theory, but then in practice, the signal that gets out of the pins of the disk reader might be hard to interpret because of some kind of proprietary architecture of the wires...?

PS: please don't judge if it reads like I don't know what I'm talking about. I'm trying to make sense of this stream/drive insanity ;)